# Consume many web api endpoints (identical)

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a list of identical web api endpoints.

URL1/Products
URL2/Products
URL3/Products
......

The result of each of them is JSON (also identical)

I need to combine the results from each API in one "main" result.

How to consume web api list? And get combined result?
What approach should be used? Best practices?
Thanks.

P.S. ASP WebAPI, using now RestSharp as a client, .Net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Show what you have tried so far and where you are having problems in a [mcve]. What you are asking for currently is too broad as there are many approaches to solving this problem.

Comment: I dont know the approach, so there is no code for this.
Existing code: consume one API (not list of them).
One API its not a problem.

Comment: The show the one API and it should help in getting us started with the list. you are basically trying to repeat the one API access for multiple calls.

Comment: I don't expect a ready solution.
Interested in the main idea.
For example, I must create an API client List<RestClient> apiClients = new List<RestClient>();

Iterate through it in a loop and run each one to execute.

Or use Rx or Polly.